# ASP.NET Core 3.1 app won't run while the 3.1 runtime is installed

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

When I attempt to run an ASP.NET Core 3.1 App with the command `dotnet run` it won't run due to the error below.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.12' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.32 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.17 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

It attempted to find `6.0.12` while the app has nothing to with .NET 6.

And this is how .csproj file look like.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>xxxxxx</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>xxxxxxxx</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.1.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.1.0</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The OS is Ubuntu WSL.

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.426 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.408 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Any ideas on why it won't run, and what needs to be done?
Thank you in advance!

I tried to check the installed runtimes with command `dotnet --list-runtimes`. And it turns out 3.1 is already installed.

Comment: I think you're gonna have to just bite the bullet and install version 6.0.12 of the framework

Comment: First of all it is very strange that you have 6 version SDK but no matching runtime. Other then that without a [mre] is hard to guess what is happening.

Comment: Maybe you can get additionnal info with enabling diagnostics...
Like: dotnet run --verbosity diag <myproj>.csproj

Comment: Actually, I had 6.0.12 installed. It turns out I had installed SDKs and Runtimes on WSL manually, this happened right after I upgraded Ubuntu version to 22.04. I guess something was messed up after the upgrade. I manually installed 6.0.12 again, and the error is gone. Thanks, everyone!